# Update xml file during copy task

Tags: xml, groovy, gradle

What would be the best way to update a specific xml file in a zip archive during a Copy type task?

What I have so far:

```
def unzip() {

    copy {
        def zipFile = configurations.tomcat.singleFile

        from zipTree(zipFile)
        into 'dir'

        eachFile { fileCopyDetails ->

            file = fileCopyDetails.file

            if ( file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith('conf' + File.separator + 'context.xml') ) {
                def contextXml = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)
                String contextStr = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(contextXml)

                println 'xml before:\n' + contextStr

                contextXml.appendNode { 
                    a('value')
                }

                contextStr = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(contextXml)
                println 'xml after:\n' + contextStr

                file.withWriter { outWriter ->
                    XmlUtil.serialize( new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{ mkp.yield contextXml }, outWriter )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that it only updates the xml file in the 'tmp' folder and not the xml file in the final 'dir' folder.

Thanks in advance,
PM

Comment: The solution depends on what exactly you are trying to update. Can you post the "update"?

Comment: Hi @BenjaminMuschko, lets say for example an Apache Tomcat server zip which we unzip into 'dir'. During the unzip, we want to update the conf/server.xml's Http port from '8080' to '8090'. I've tried doing this using eachFile { ... } but the updated xml only appears in the 'tmp' folder and not in the final 'dir' folder. Cheers, PM.